# When app is onPause() I keep on receiving error messages on the LogCat

Tags: android, android-asynctask, httpclient, logcat

Now I have the following class, which I instantiate in my main activity in order to retrieve some data from the Internet.

As you can see the class contains an AsyncTask which performs the data collection form Internet.

When my activity is paused (via the BACK button on the emulator) I stop the AsyncTask.

Nevertheless LogCat continues to show messages as the AsyncTask is still continuing to try to fetch data from Internet.

Here is the LogCat, it never stops...

```
12-24 09:36:48.806: E/grabXML(698): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Manager is shut down.
12-24 09:36:48.816: E/grabXML(698): Exception fetching data
12-24 09:36:48.816: E/grabXML(698): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Manager is shut down.
12-24 09:36:48.836: E/grabXML(698): Exception fetching data
12-24 09:36:48.836: E/grabXML(698): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Manager is shut down.
12-24 09:36:48.846: E/grabXML(698): Exception fetching data
12-24 09:36:48.846: E/grabXML(698): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Manager is shut down.
12-24 09:36:48.856: E/grabXML(698): Exception fetching data
12-24 09:36:48.856: E/grabXML(698): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Manager is shut down.
12-24 09:36:48.966: E/grabXML(698): Exception fetching data
12-24 09:36:48.966: E/grabXML(698): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Manager is shut down.
12-24 09:36:48.996: E/grabXML(698): Exception fetching data
12-24 09:36:48.996: E/grabXML(698): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Manager is shut   down.
12-24 09:36:49.037: E/grabXML(698): Exception fetching data
12-24 09:36:49.037: E/grabXML(698): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Manager is shut down.
```

Here is my class

```
public class Grab{
    public String url;
    public String srt = "cav";
    public boolean flag = false;
    public GrabXml g;
    public Grab (String u){
        url = u;
    } 

    public String vai(){
        g = new GrabXml();
        g.execute();
        Log.e("", srt);
        while(!flag){
            // nothing
        };
        g.cancel(true);
        return srt;
    }

    public void fermaGrab() {
        g.cancel(true); 
    }

    public class GrabXml extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void>{
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            Log.e("", "arrivo al do in background");
            Log.e("", url);
            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet getMethod = new HttpGet(url);
            try {
                ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                srt = client.execute(getMethod, responseHandler);
                Log.e("", "passo per GrabXML");
            }
            catch (Throwable t) {
                android.util.Log.e("grabXML", "Exception fetching data", t);
            }
            flag = true;
            client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... item) {
            // nothing
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
            flag = true;      
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try to override the onCancel(); method in the AsyncTask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution to the riddle: see [I continue to receive messages after Activity is destroyed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14020795/1815311)

The Service was actually being killed properly.

The point was that the Service contains an infinite loop, and the loop continued even when the Service was cancelled/destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem inside the below line line

```
       client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
```

You will find more [Description of your Solution](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/IJv8Z6HMwpE)

[This is the original Apache documentation](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html#d4e646) that can also help for better understanding.

Comment: Thanks, but I do not think this is the problem, because as you can see fro the code I cancel (or I THINK I cancel) the AsyncTask as well, therefore I expect the client not to be called anymore... Thanks again