# I continue to receive messages after Activity is destroyed

Tags: android, handler, message

Hi everybody and Merry Christmas.

Please see this snippet of code.

As you can see there is an Handler that receives messages form a Service.

When the Activty is destroyed, I take care of destroying the Service, nevertheless it seems like the Service is still sending back messages to the Handler (which I don't think it is the case).

For some reason the Handler seems to stay alive and post:

```
 Log.e("","MESSAGGIO RICEVUTO");
```

like it is continuing to receive messages.

Thanks for your help!!!

```
private String url;
    private String url2;
private WebView browser;
private HttpClient client;
private List<Forecast> forecasts=new ArrayList<Forecast>();
public String responseBody;
    public ArrayList<Stock> lt;
    public LocalService mService;
    boolean mBound = false;
    public MyAdapter myAdap;
    public Messenger messenger;
    public Grab g;
    public Handler handler;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        url2=getString(R.string.url2);
        Log.e("", "arrivo a prima di forecast");
        g = new Grab(url2);
        String s = g.vai();
        Log.e("", s);
        Log.e("", "passo oltre l'invocazione al grab");
        lt = new MyParser(s).parseResp();
        ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        myAdap= new MyAdapter(lt, this); 
        lv.setAdapter(myAdap);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new myListener());

        handler=new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            Log.e("","MESSAGGIO RICEVUTO");
            lt = mService.ritira();
            myAdap.notifyDataSetChanged();
            g.fermaGrab();
            }
            };
        messenger = new Messenger(handler);         
    }
```

This is the Service:

```
public class LocalService extends Service {
    public Messenger messenger;
public int i;
   public ArrayList<Stock> al;
    public DefaultHttpClient client;
// Binder given to clients
    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
    public Task t;

    /**
     * Class used for the client Binder.  Because we know this service always
     * runs in the same process as its clients, we don't need to deal with IPC.
     */
    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        LocalService getService() {
            // Return this instance of LocalService so clients can call public methods
            return LocalService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Log.e("", "sono nel service");      
        messenger = (Messenger) intent.getExtras().get("messenger");
        return mBinder;
    }  

    class Task extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {     
        Log.e("Sono nel AsyncTask del Service", Integer.toBinaryString(i));
 /////////INIZIA IL CASINO
        client=new DefaultHttpClient();
        for(int in=0;;in++)
        {       
        for(int i=0;i<al.size();i++)
        {
            String srt="";
            String url     =getString(R.string.dettaglio1).concat("'"+al.get(i).simbolo+"'").concat(getString(R.string.    dettaglio2));

            HttpGet getMethod=new HttpGet(url);

            try {
                ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler=new BasicResponseHandler();
                srt=client.execute(getMethod, responseHandler);
                //Log.e("", "passo per GrabXML");
                int inizio = srt.indexOf("<company data=\"");
                int fine = srt.indexOf("\"/>",inizio+15);
                String s =srt.substring(inizio+15,fine).substring(0, 10);

                al.get(i).setNome(s);
                Log.e("",al.get(i).nome);
                //Log.e("",Integer.toString((al.get(i).nome.length())));

                inizio = srt.indexOf("<last data=\"");
                fine = srt.indexOf("\"/>",inizio+12);
                al.get(i).setPrezzo(srt.substring(inizio+12,fine));
                //Log.e("",Float.toString(al.get(i).prezzo));

                inizio = srt.indexOf("<perc_change data=\"");
                fine = srt.indexOf("\"/>",inizio+19);
                al.get(i).setCambiamento(srt.substring(inizio+19,fine));
                //Log.e("",Float.toString(al.get(i).cambiamento));
            }
            catch (Throwable t) {
                android.util.Log.e("grabXML", "Exception fetching data", t);
                    }           
            }
/////////INIZIA IL CASINO
        Collections.sort(al, new Comparator<Stock>(){
              public int compare(Stock s1, Stock s2) {
                return s1.nome.compareToIgnoreCase(s2.nome);
              }
            });         

        Message msg=Message.obtain();

        try {
            messenger.send(msg);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        SystemClock.sleep(6000);

        }
        /////////FINISCE IL CASINO      

        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... unused) {
            }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {     
            }

    }



    public void stop() {
        Log.e("", "passo per lo stop del Service");
        t.cancel(true);
        client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        return;
    }


}
```

I shut down the Service on the main Activity in the onDestroy():

```
 protected void onDestroy() {
    Log.e("ondestroy","passo per ondestroy"); 
    //handler.removeMessages();
    mService.stop();
    g.fermaGrab();
    handler.removeMessages(333); 
    //g=null;
    super.onDestroy();   
    }
```

Comment: You'll need to post more code, especially how the service should shut down and how the service generates these messages that it sends to the handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're continuing receiving a message from your service because of this infinite loop

```
class Task extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {  
            for (int in = 0;; in++) { 
               // .. Other definition

               Message msg = Message.obtain();

               try {
               messenger.send(msg);
               } catch (RemoteException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
               }
               SystemClock.sleep(6000);

            }
        }
}
```

A conditionless for-loop is doing an infinite process, so your service's thread is still sending you a message right?

Just put `!isCancelled()` in your loop, and you can now stop your loop and `Asynctask`

```
for (int in = 0; !isCancelled() ; in++) { 
    // ...
}
```

Comment: thanks, but if I kill the  AsyncTask that contains the loop, doesn't it kill the loop as well??

Comment: The loop is still alive even you kill your ``Asynctask``, unless you put ``!isCancelled()`` in your infinite for-loop's condition.

Answer (score 1):

Please see this. It is not answer to your question. It will help you to get answer,

[How to stop the handler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5038038/how-to-stop-the-handler)

Comment: @ Thirumal Valavan thank you, tried handler.removeMessages(what) but no sucess...

Comment: Please this link. I will help you. It is kill the service.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9389407/stop-or-kill-a-service